# How to keep Javascript from breaking

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to keep one bad Javascript call from breaking my entire code base? Right now, if someone in my app makes a bad Javascript call, then the script in the rest of the application stops working.

Comment: Are you asking for exception handling?

Comment: A little more detail on your application's architecture, and used framework(s) would help... In this form the question way too generic to be answered.

Comment: Are you asking "How to keep MY Javascript from breaking"  hummmmm

Comment: Seriously?  Stop downing peoples reputation and then perhaps you would get a worthwhile answer.  Your ignorance is astounding

Comment: Who makes a "bad Javascript call" and where? And no, with no mechanism you can prevent breaking your whole app if only one does the right "wrong Javascript call".

Comment: Not asking about exception handling, and was hoping there was some generic answer like detecting when a bad javascript call was made and refreshing my script or whatever but it seems that I will just have to make sure any javascript added is up to a higher standard. Thanks for the help everyone and sorry the question was so genaric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Exception Handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#Exception_Handling_Statements) to attempt to work around this problem - in particular, `try` and `catch`. That would be most effective if there are particular areas of the application that are fragile and that seem to break most often.

But this might just be a symptom of a larger problem. If you find that your application is broken on a regular basis, the problem could lie with your development process. Perhaps you need to develop functional/unit tests, test your application more rigorously prior to deployment, understand why individual developers are not fixing their own mistakes (or "releasing" so many in the first place), etc.

Comment: Well we are in late development with a hard push to get everything finished before Christmas when we just started using real data. And we should have a more rigorous development cycle but you know how it is. Also we are using primefaces and you have to be really careful with that. You know just tired of the business side wondering why my stuff stops working cause another developer decides to throw in some untested java code real fast lol.

Comment: Also thanks for the try catch suggestion I will pass it on to every :)

Answer (score -2):

Yeah wrap the code in:

```
try {

} catch (e) {

}
```